# Try with resources on resource not created in try block

Tags: java

I have the following try block and fs which is a closeable was created previously.

Will it get closed or do we need to explicitly close it in a finally?

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)))) {
...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is fs? Every resource that is declared **within** the try-with-resources parentheses is closed afterwards. It has the same effect as if you would close it manually in a finally block. Every resource declared before or within the block itself will not be closed automatically. Every object that implements the `Autoclosable` interface can be used in a try-with-resources. See more here [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: It's Hadoop FS, but it's created prior to getting to that try block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) you can found that

> Resources are initialized in left-to-right order. If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the try-with-resources statement are closed. If all resources initialize successfully, the try block executes as normal and then all non-null resources of the try-with-resources statement are closed.
>
> **Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized**. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources. Such an exception is suppressed if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource.

Only the instance declare in the *ResourceSpecification* block will be closed in the opposite order of the declaration.

So to answer you, since `fs` is declared before this *try-with-resources*, the instance won't be closed.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it has more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Only `reader.close()` is called; conceptually just before program control reaches the `}`, which will include the case when an exception is thrown in the `try` block.

But you need to deal with `fs` in the normal way.

Comment: but couldn´t he declare `fs` as a seperate source in the block and use it for the following sources?

Comment: I could but the point is that fs was instantiated externally.